# htaccess URL Rewrite problem, 404 error on redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**EDIT**: I have changed the original code and left my original request below.

I think I have fixed the problem, but if someone could go over this coding and tell me if there is something I should clear up / be neater / fix, please do let me know.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(unknownthemes)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?unknownthemes/(.*?)/?$ /unknownthemes?unk=$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /unknownthemes\?unk=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?unknownthemes$ /unknownthemes/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|events|unknownthemes)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /events?f=$1&y=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|events|unknownthemes)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /events?f=$1&y=$2

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /events\?f=([^\&\ ]+)\&y=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?events$ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [NC]
```

Thank you very much for giving this a look and any feedback, help will be truly appreciated.

**Original post**:
I currently have a website which uses the ReWrite rules in htaccess to transfer users to the correct part of the website pushing them mostly through 1 script. This works perfectly fine on my current host (with cPanel), I am having to move to another host who has their own control panel and for some reason it no longer works. They state "modrewrite is enabled", they can no longer assist so I am coming here in hopes that you amazing people can help.

I am not that great with htaccess coding and this has been a bit of trial and error to make it, but once I got it to work I left it.

Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wcw\.craig-uk\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove slash if file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?unknownthemes/(.*?)/?$ /unknownthemes?unk=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /unknownthemes\?unk=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?unknownthemes$ /unknownthemes/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|events)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /events?f=$1&y=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|events)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /events?f=$1&y=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /events\?f=([^\&\ ]+)\&y=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?events$ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]

# Redirect to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [NC]
```

I have shown all the code incase something is conflicting (apart from the php selection and errordocument forwards).
This should do the following:

- Force the site through https
- Remove the .php extension
- Run a code like https://wcw.craig-uk.com/unknownthemes/87_12 through the script https://wcw.craig-uk.com/unknownthemes?unk=87_12 and if no selected after then point them just to the script
- Run the main site of https://wcw.craig-uk.com/Pro/1989 through https://wcw.craig-uk.com/events?f=Pro&y=1989 and if entered directly then it send you to https://wcw.craig-uk.com/Pro/1989

Now all this works on the Craig-UK domain (old server) but not on MyDiv (new server)
I have uploaded the exact same scripting to my new host but with changing the domain and the removal of the .php part works perfect but the links on the left bring a 404 error, and the links in the unknown themes page bring up a 500 error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I would love to move my sites to my new host.

EDIT

Comment: I have changed the code, so I have edited the original post. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you